# ¿Cómo evito que los iconos del Navigation Drawer desaparezcan?

Tags: java, android, navigationview

Tengo una aplicación móvil creada con Android Studio, esta tiene un Navigation Drawer y cada vez que doy clic a un icono del menú, envío a un contenedor un Fragment, y así con cada una de las vistas que conforman mi app. Dependiendo del Fragment que envíe al contenedor, así aparecen y desaparecen iconos que he colocado en la Toolbar del Navigation Drawer. El problema es que cuando giro el dispositivo y este adapta la nueva vista dependiendo si es horizontal o vertical, los iconos que tengo en esta Toolbar desaparecen. ¿Alguien sabe cómo evitar esto?

Comment: ¿Cómo cargas los iconos? Al cambiar la orientación del móvil la actividad se vuelve a crear y quizás no estás cargando bien los iconos, vendría bien ver algo de código

Comment: Noté lo siguiente, si coloco: android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" entonces los iconos de la toolbar del Drawer no se ocultan y funcionan bien, el problema es que si agrego esta linea de código mis layuots no se van actualizar..